# multi texture handling with single shader in blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders

I am new to blender, but i have worked in other packages professionally over the years. I was wondering, if blender has a system, where a single shader can handle multiple textures based on the object its applied to.
It can be extremely helpful , when there are so many objects in the scene, say called wood , but only their textures are different for each object. This will greatly reduce the number of material created, also manual assignment on each of the object.

So, the idea is , the objects have string primvars, which can be joined over to create a folder , where the textures will be stored. And as long as texture sets like Albedo,SPR etc is present in the folder, it would call them at rendertime.
Please, let me know , if its possible to do that.
Much Appreciated,
Thanks,

Comment: I don't think so. Shader can not be "parameterized" by textures. Or if you can do some per object parameter (like pass index) that won't allow to dig into a folder to get pictures.